# Help me identify a 80's (probably)series with a robotic(or alien) face attacker

Tags: story-identification, space

More from my memories: the "face attacker" kills people, has miniature needle inside it, and leave silver(hope so silver, we had a B&W television then) colored, vein like pattern on the victim's face. The TV show begins(or ends) with moving forward in a metal tube, while you see the credits. Probably it was on Sky Channel. Sry I was 5-6 years old, thanks for every help.

Comment: The robotic face attackers remind me a little bit of the 1984 movie _Runaway_. See [this snippet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9zzHnRYxtc) for instance. But that's not what you meant is it?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure that the main setting was a spaceship, or a starbase. The "face attacker" has no legs, it's like a smaller snake with metal coating - probably no more than half meter long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing the 1975 Doctor Who episode ["Revenge of the Cybermen"](http://www.thedoctorwhosite.co.uk/cybermen/cybermen-episode-guide/#revenge):

- Face attacker: No legs, like a smaller snake with metal coating, half meter long, leaves colored vein-like pattern on victim's face = Cybermat, [third generation, according to this site](http://www.thedoctorwhosite.co.uk/cybermen/cybermen-designs/cybermats/):

[image: 3rd Generation of Cybermats screenshot]

- The opening/closing credits of the Tom Baker era Doctor Who moves through a trippy tube-like thing:

Also, Cybermats scared the heck out of me when I was a kid.

Comment: Definitely the correct answer, thanks!